# How to append data properly in the next line of an array?

Tags: python

def FunctionA():

```
...
...
...
sol #Here,sol is an array

output = []
for i in sol:
    output.append(FunctionB(i))
print(output)
print(output[0,:])
```

def FunctionB(i):

```
metrics = [i[1],i[2],i[3]]
return metrics
```

driver()

**Question No. 01:**

Whenever I run the code, the Output array becomes-

```
[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2], ... ... ,[xn,yn,zn]]
```

But I want the output array to be as follows-

> [[x1,y1,z1],
>
> [x2,y2,z2],
> ... ,
>
> ... ,
>
> [xn,yn,zn]]

**How do I do this?**

**Question No. 02:**

And in the code, to print the values of first column, I am using this-

print(output[0,:])
this gives the following error.

> print(output[0,:])
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

**How do I get all the values of contents of any particular column?**

Comment: Hello, try to delete the comma and leave [0:]

Comment: @MegaKarg This gives me all the values of the "Output" array starting from index 0 to the end. This is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Numpy may help you to get your expected format

```
import string
import numpy as np

def FunctionA():

        sol = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

        output = []
        for i in sol:
                output.append(FunctionB(i))
        output = np.array(output)
        print(output)
        print(output[:,0]) #Column
        print(output[0,:]) #Row

def FunctionB(i):
        metrics = [i[0],i[1],i[2]]
        return metrics

FunctionA()
```